# Angular User Idle Settings for 20 minutes:

Tags: angular

In the angular front end application, I have installed the library angular-user-idle for implementing the idle timeout functionality. I would like to know the settings for 
 idle:**_ ,timeout:_** ,ping:___ in my app.module.ts file.

requirement is if the user is idle for 15 minutes I should display a modal window which will have a timer for 5 minutes. After the 5 minutes are over, the user should be logged out.

in the idle-message.component.ts I have the following settings:

```
minutesDisplay = 0
secondsDisplay = 0
idleTimer = 15
logoutTimer = 5
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post what you've tried including the TypeScript and HTML if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

According to angular-user-idle's documentation you can set the idle, timeout and ping in your module like so..

```js
UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: 600, timeout: 300, ping: 120})
```

You can adjust those values to meet your needs. A brief explanation is below on these params.

- idle - The amount of seconds a user can be idle before the timeout begins
- timeout - The amount of seconds before the timeout ends
- ping - is used if you want to perform some action periodically every n-minutes in lifecycle of timer (from start timer to timeout).

Comment: are above in miliseconds? 300 means how many minutes?

Comment: Those are in seconds. (Default values: `idle` is 600 (10 minutes), `timeout` is 300 (5 minutes)